# Apostrophe CMS + Express.js Backend + Angular integration

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, apostrophe, apostrophe-cms

I've been trying to integrate Apostrophe CMS with a CRM platform that we have running on a node.js+express.js backend, but am finding it a bit difficult.

I'll detail the setup before asking:

- We have two parallel platforms: **client-cms** and **client-server**, where **-cms** is APOS and **-server** is our backend API built with node.js and express.js
  [image]
- **client-server** has a frontend built in angular that runs on the separate project **client-ng**.
  The first step towards integration was to create a custom module in Apostrophe in **/lib/modules/client-server/** with a copy of our node.js + express.js backend. **client-server** on Apos
  Then we created **/lib/modules/apostrophe-express/index.js** which contains the following:

`module.exports = {
      session: {
        secret: 'xxxxxxxxxd80e52'
      },
      csrf: {
        exceptions: [
          '/user/login',
          '/api/v1/*/**'
        ]
      },
      port: 4000
      };`

While navigating our site, the majority of the content is loaded from Apostrophe modules, but for logged in users there are specific sections that are rendered through angular components and that load data from **client-server**'s API.

However, both Apostrophe and our Angular frontend should share a number of JS and CSS dependencias, as well as common data, such as Apostrophe's navigation menu.

The issues:

- We have recently been experiencing intermittent 403 errors when trying to load data from the client-server through its /api/v1/. We have added the exceptions, but would like to know if there is a way to debug those 403 errors.
- Our **client-server** handles the session and info for all logged in users, but we're not sure how to hand this down to Apostrophe for display. For example, how could we get my layout.html to pull the avatar and user_id from /api/v1/ in order to consistently display this info across the entire site?

One possible solution we're working on in order to solve the need for a unified UI is by using apostrophe-headless. Ideally we're aiming to create a fragment that sends a rendered UI to angular, ready for print, or in a less idea case, send the `data` object so that angular has all it needs to recreate the UI.

I think headless along with fragments could possibly solve the issue with the shared UI.

Thoughts?

Comment: If the errors are intermittent they might not actually be from Apostrophe at all, but it is easy to check. Around line 501 of lib/modules/apostrophe-assets/index.js you'll find where we are setting `res.statusCode = 403;` and you can add logging there temporarily, including logging `req.url` to see if it matches your exceptions.

Comment: As for the more general integration issue, you can use an `apostrophe-pages:beforeSend` promise event listener to pause and grab something from your Angular side, then add it to `req.data` so it's visible on `data` in your layout. Example here: https://apostrophecms.org/docs/events.html